# Stored procedure properties page missing in SSMS when connected to an Azure SQL database

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am connecting to on premises SQL Server and an Azure SQL database that is in a pool. Both from same SSMS instance.

When I right click on a stored procedure in any database on the on-premise server, I see the properties option and can add/modify permissions. But the Azure SQL connection does not show the properties option for stored procedures so I must GRANT in T-SQL.

There is a lot of info in the properties general as well as permission I'd like to have the SSMS access to see easily. Is there a setting in Azure SQL that enables / disables properties?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL database doesn't support the all the `properties` settings in SSMS.

For example, SSMS supports Azure SQL `database properties` settings:
[image]

But as you found that it doesn't support `Stored Procedure properties` setting.

> Is there a setting in Azure SQL that enables / disables properties?

No, there isn't such settings in Portal or SSMS. No matter which account(admin or db_owner) you login to the Azure SQL database.

The only way is you grant it in T_SQL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I wasn't going crazy! It's just a "it is what it is" situation. Hopefully ms will get around to it sooner than later.

Comment: @LouNobilé You're welcome. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that, new to the forum. Thx for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Azure SQL Database issue, but a database permissions issue.

Are you connecting in the same way - i.e. both using a SQL login?

You will need to ensure that you grant the same permissions for the user on both databases, one way might be to script out the permissions from the on-premises database and run the query on the Azure one.  You should still ensure that you do this at the lowest level possible so that you don't grant excessive permissions. I suggest at the schema level

The permission that you need at the minimum level is:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::<my schema name> TO <my user>
```

Comment: I am connecting as the server admin (in  azure portal) which enters any db as dbo. To be sure after reading your answer I also used a connection that is a db user that is in db_owner. Both cases, when I right click on a stored procedure there is no "Properties" option in the context menu. Aside, there is a "Properties" option when I right click on a table. I have full permissions and can see and  do anything with them in that database. (all databases with the server admin).

Comment: Ah, got you now. That is by design, those pages are not currently exposed for Azure SQL Database and you will need to gather the properties using T-SQL queries. I think tables are the only objects that expose properties from Azure SQL Database - and even this is a subset of an on-premises database.